# Getting one single table from 3 tables where 2 of the tables have the same column

Tags: sql

I have the following three tables in my sql

```
+------+--------+------+------------+
| id   | letter | date | identifier |
+------+--------+------+------------+
|    1 | a      | mar  |        100 |
+------+--------+------+------------+

+------+--------+------+------------+
| id   | letter | date | identifier |
+------+--------+------+------------+
|    1 | a      | mar  |        100 |
+------+--------+------+------------+

+------+--------+------+------------+
| id   | letter | date | identifier |
+------+--------+------+------------+
|   10 | b      | mar  |        200 |
|   10 | c      | feb  |        300 |
+------+--------+------+------------+
```

the goal here is to combine the two tables based on the dates

```
+------+------+--------+--------+------+
| ida  | idb  | letter | letter | date |
+------+------+--------+--------+------+
|    1 |   10 | a      | b      | mar  |
|    1 |   10 | null   | c      | feb  |
+------+------+--------+--------+------+
```

I have the following query below

```
select ida, idb, table2.letter, table3.letter, table2.date, table3.date
from table2 
left join table1 A  
   on A.ida = table2.id  
left join table3 
 on A.idb = table3.id group by table2.date;
```

but the result is the following

```
+------+------+--------+--------+------+------+
| ida  | idb  | letter | letter | date | date |
+------+------+--------+--------+------+------+
|    1 |   10 | a      | b      | mar  | mar  |
+------+------+--------+--------+------+------+
```

Comment: What is the difference between two first tables

Comment: Both tables are same

Comment: What kind of SQL are you using? You need `group by` and then `group_concat()` or `string_agg()` depending on the type of sql

Comment: 1) `Both tables are same`  If the duplicate table isn't relevant to the question, remove it.  2) What's the data type of the "date" column? The name implies date, but the sample values are strings ("mar", "feb")? 3) What happens to the expected results when there's a letter "D", "E", "F", etc...?